# How to consolidate or collect all the texures used in a project?

Tags: texturing

I want to collect all the textures used in my blender scene so i can save pack them into a folder for archiving purpose (so later i can load it into other machine ) ?

What the fastest way to do this so i don't have to go through them one by one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to go:

1. File > External data > Pack all into .blend.
2. Save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) - this will actually pack the textures.
3. File > External data > Unpack All Into Files > Write Files to current directory.

This will create a folder containing all textures that were packed.

[image]

Comment: This is super useful. However, how is this different from 'append'? (If the answer is too complicated, I might ask a new question)

Comment: Hello :). *Append* is used to copy data from other blendfiles. Appended textures aren't automatically packed afaik.